# GeoPandas spatial join generates error in QGIS 3.8 Python console

Tags: qgis, python, spatial-join, geopandas, qgis-python-console

I want to execute a spatial join using GeoPandas in the Python console QGIS 3.8 like this:

```
dfsjoin = gpd.sjoin(point, polygon)
```

but it doesn't work. It always shows the following error:

```
Exception ignored in: <function Handle.__del__ at 0x0000026EC6680BF8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\rtree\index.py", line 895, in __del__
    self.destroy()
  File "C:\OSGEO4~1\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\rtree\index.py", line 884, in destroy
    self._destroy(self._ptr)
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x0000000000000001
```

But, if I run it in OSGeo4W Shell it runs correctly as following:

[image]

What is the different between python console in QGIS app and in OSGeo4W Shell?
And how can I fix it?

Comment: the error is due to [rtree](https://pypi.org/project/Rtree/) and not GeoPandas (Geopandas use rtree)

Comment: But, It runs correctly when I try in OSGEO4W Shell